# How to access MySQL server running on Raspberry Pi from MySQL Workbench on another computer in the same LAN?

Tags: mysql

I have installed MySQL server on a Raspberry Pi with Reserved IP address. I have set up a new user for the SQL server with the % host. On my Mac Mini, I have installed MySQL Workbench and am trying to connect to the server running on the Pi. I have tried with and without Remote Management SSH, same error message. When using SSH, the credentials are correct and authentication is successful
WITH REMOTE MANAGMENT: [image: Remote Management Menu]
WITHOUT REMOTE MANAGEMENT: [image: CONNECTION Menu]

ERROR without Remote Management: Failed to Connect to MySQL at 192.168.0.60:3306 with user daniel. Unable to connect to localhost

I tried opening the port 3306 on the Pi and allowing any IP as host for the MySQL account. The server runs and I can access and control it from the Raspberry Pi, just not my computer.